# Errors using Laravel's Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 models - User and RoleUser. Each user is assigned to a role. So I defined a one-to-one relationship by declaring a 'role' method on the User model.

```
 public function role(){
        return $this->hasOne('Vanguard\RoleUser', 'user_id');
 }
```

This is my Role Model

```
class RoleUser extends Model
{
    //
    public $table = 'role_user';

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'role_id'];

}
```

In controller, I am trying to fetch users with role_id = 2 but the query keeps returning all users (i.e. 3) instead of just one user. 
This is my controller

```
 $users = User::with(['role' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('role_id', 2);
        }])->get();
```

Please what is causing this?

Comment: What version of Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a scope with `with` will only add the scope to the eager loaded relation, regardless of if it exists. To achieve what you want you need to do a `whereHas` too.

```
$users = User::whereHas('role', function ($q) {
    $q->where('role_id', 2);
})->with(['role' => function ($q) {
    $q->where('role_id', 2);
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the query to be something like this:

`User::all()->with('role')->where('role_id', 2)->get()`

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have defined that:

- A user has one role.
- A role has many users.

then you can simply write query as:

```
$role = Role::with('users')->find(2);
$users = $role->users;
```

The above example will give you all users with role id 2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each user may only have one role, then give this a try:

In your **User** model:

```
class User extends Model 
{
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(RoleUser::class);
    }
}
```

In your **RoleUser** model:

```
class RoleUser extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Now, get the data you need (try this in Tinker first):

```
// Users with role_id 2
$users = User::where('role_id', 2)->get();

// Eager load the Role model to get the entire Role record for each user
$users = User::with('role')->where('role_id', 2)->get();

// Get role's where role_id is 2, and eager load the users
$role = RoleUser::with('users')->where('id', 2)->get();
```